# No data retrieved while calling a stored procedure

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to call a stored procedure from VC++.

Here is what the stored procedure looks like:

```
public static void SqlStoredProcedure2(string name, out byte[] backup)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT EmployeePhoto FROM [dbo].[DimEmployee] where FirstName like '%@name%'";
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        backup = null;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            backup = (byte[])reader["EmployeePhoto"];
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

And the c++ code looks like:

```
RETCODE retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT,hdbc,&hstmt);
retcode = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_VARCHAR, 5, 0, "Alan", 0, &cbParm1);
unsigned char ptr[8000] = "";
cbParm2 = 8000;
retcode = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQL_C_BINARY, SQL_VARBINARY, 0, 0, ptr, 0, &cbParm2);
retcode = SQLExecDirectA(hstmt, (UCHAR*)"{call SqlStoredProcedure2(?, ?)}", SQL_NTS);
```

There is no error when I check returned code but nothing comes in `ptr`? What is wrong here?

Comment: my experience of SQLCLR is that it is a PoS. Why are you using this when it could be written much easier in SQL, and the performance would be much greater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i resolve the issue , here is right way to call it.

```
    SQLRETURN retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, &hstmt);
    if ( (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS) && (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) )
    {
        printf("SQLAllocHandle(hstmt1) Failed\n\n");
        return;
    }

    retcode = SQLPrepareA(hstmt,(SQLCHAR*)"{call StoreProcedure2(?)}",SQL_NTS);

    SQLSMALLINT NumParams1, DataType1, DecimalDigits1, Nullable1;
    SQLULEN ParamSize1;
    unsigned char input1[50000] = "";
    SQLLEN inputlen1 = sizeof(input1);
    SQLINTEGER cbValue1 = sizeof(input1);//actual size of data in or out

    retcode = SQLDescribeParam(hstmt, 1, &DataType1, &ParamSize1, &DecimalDigits1, &Nullable1);
    retcode = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQL_C_BINARY, DataType1, ParamSize1, DecimalDigits1, &input1, inputlen1 ,&cbValue1);

    retcode = SQLExecDirectA(hstmt, (UCHAR*)"{call StoreProcedure2(?)}", SQL_NTS);
    if ( (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS) && (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) ) 
    {
        printf("SQLExecDirect Failed\n\n");
        extract_error(hstmt,SQL_HANDLE_STMT);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you unit test the C# code before the integration.  There are a lot of problems with you C# code.  The first one is you don't have the parameter passed in the C# code.

Add the following before you execute the reader.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@name", name );
```

In addition, your while loop makes no sense (you are ignoring all the pictures but the last one) and you should use `using` for the cmd.

As a side note be aware -- a search like this with a wildcard at the start and end is going to be very very slow.

SQL Server has full text search available as a seperate feature.

Comment: Thanks for reply, well now i am getting exception of size , the default size of bytr buffer is 8000 but size of data is approx 15000, how i can ghange size of out buffer ?

Comment: huh?  You have these lines in your code: `unsigned char ptr[8000] = ""; cbParm2 = 8000;`  The `8000` seems a dead giveaway to me.

Answer (score 0):

" 8000 seems a dead giveaway to me. "  sorry for that,
why i put 8000 there because this is how generated query looks like,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SqlStoredProcedure2] @name [nvarchar](4000),
@backup [varbinary](8000)    OUTPUT
AS EXTERNAL NAME [Database1].[StoredProcedures].[SqlStoredProcedure2];
```

i think it will get change once i change size but this did not happen.

now i am trying to change size of buffer.

Answer (score 0):

ok i have resolve size issue , i need to use

```
SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)
```

parameter  so sql store procedure looks like

c#

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void SqlStoredProcedure2(string name, 
[SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)]out byte[] backup)
```

and generated query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SqlStoredProcedure2] @name [nvarchar](4000),
@backup [varbinary](MAX)     OUTPUT
AS EXTERNAL NAME [Database1].[StoredProcedures].[SqlStoredProcedure2];
```

i still had bad luck nothing comming in output ptr in c++.